# Amazon AWS Getting started, initial cost estimate

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to get started using AWS.  My IT department has asked for a cost estimate.  How do I provide this, I plan to use the following

Compute
Storage and Content Delivery
Database

This is for a basic beginners project.

Comment: Use aws simple calculator https://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html

Comment: AWS also offers a free tier that you may qualify for: https://aws.amazon.com/free/

Answer (score 0):

This is the best option for providing your IT department Total Cost of Ownership for AWS Resources

https://awstcocalculator.com

Answer (score 0):

You can use this calculator provided by AWS team and you can create or save this on Amazon and Share it with your respective teams.

[Calculator for AWS Services Estimation bills](https://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html)

Like for Example I've created a lift and shift bill using the same :

[Migration Plan - LiftNShift](https://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html#r=IAD&s=EC2&key=calc-F35F6E10-2F29-4869-9AAF-60EAFC80A0DE)